# .getDataRange not returning an Array - Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a Google Form to help us measure some data.  The problem I am running into and I can't seem to figure out is why when is it when I setup the .getDataRange it only returns one value and not an array of all my data?

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Timestamp            Barcode      Start or Finish   Picker  Number of Units
4/5/2017 8:00:50    2017-04-03-213                          20
4/5/2017 8:10:19    2017-04-03-213                          20
4/5/2017 8:11:34    2017-04-03-212-Postal                   49
4/5/2017 8:23:32    2017-04-03-212-Postal                   49
4/5/2017 8:29:09    2017-04-03-212-Postal                    9
```

Here is the simple code I am running:

```
function testData() {
// active Spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getValue();

Logger.log(data);
```

Here is what my Log file Shows:

```
17-04-23 07:28:41:834 PDT] Timestamp
```

From everything I have read "data" should return an array of all the values in the sheet.  however, the log file is just returning the one value "Timestamp".  I figured I am just not doing something right, but I am just not sure what i am doing wrong.  I have spent 3+ hours trying to figure this out and now I am desperate for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var data = range.getValue();
```

with

```
var data = range.getValues();
```

Comment: thanks for your help and pointing that out to me.  I can't believe I was overlooking that.